# How do I use jQuery.post to send JSON data to a php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

This is in my javascript code. The variable dataStore is a valid JSON object and the JSON.stringify works fine - I tested with console.log() to be sure.

I'm new to jQuery and have not written a CGI application in awhile so I may be doing something incorrect here.

```
jQuery.post("taskmanager.php", JSON.stringify(dataStore), function (returnData) { 
    alert(returnData); 
});
```

The taskmanager.php script resides in the same folder as my other files ( taskmanager.html, taskmanager.css, taskmanager.js ).  This folder resides on my Windows7 folder **E:\JamesLaderoute\MySoftware\WebApp\TaskManager\code**

I'm not sure what to put into the taskmanager.php script. I thought I could do something simple like:

```
<?php

    $data = $_GET["data"];

    echo "done";

?>
```

What I don't understand is, how will the php script know that my JSON stringify information was called "data".

Also, I thought jQuery.post() takes the script name as the first argument, and then the data to be sent to the script followed by a callback function that gets called when the script returns data via **echo** calls.

The alert() does get called but it's displaying the php script rather than the string "done"

I've searched the internet (a little bit) and found examples that use something called AJAX to send data to a script like php.

I learn best with a small example, is there a good example that points out what I'm missing?  How do I get this to work?

Eventually I plan on taking whatever the JSON data is and saving it to a file on the server.  Do I need to run this all with a real server?  Right now I'm not using one but I do have WAMP setup so I could use that if that is what is required.

**Thank you to everyone who posted answers to my problem. I'm editing this post to show the actual code I ended up using to get my application working.**

JavaScript code:

```
alert(returnData); });
        $.ajax({
            url : "taskmanager.php" ,
            type : 'POST',
            data : JSON.stringify(dataStore),
            success : function(res) {
                    // Successfully sent data
                  console.log(res);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                // Unable to send data
                  console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

    $contents = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode( $contents );

    file_put_contents( "taskdata.json",  "data=".$contents );

    echo "<br>done</br>";

?>
```

Comment: need to run server first to use ajax in a page and second to be able to run the php

Comment: @charlietfl :  Thank you. I now copied my code to my WAMP  /www area and I see it is trying to run the .php file now. Using parts  of the other answers to this post I'm now able to get something running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can send data to your end point using the POST protocol. Example below

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'taskmanager.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : JSON.stringify(dataStore),
    success : function(res) {
        // Successfully sent data.
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        // Unable to send data.
        console.log(err);
    })
});
```

You may also use the $.post method, its just a preference. $.ajax provides with some extra flexibility, in case you maybe want to update your protocol to GET instead of post or numerous other instances...

More info on this here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-should-i-use-post-vs-ajax

Comment: What you did is the same as `$.post()`

Comment: @Ibu, it works the same way, except $.ajax provides some extra flexibility if needed.

Comment: need to set contentType if sending json

Comment: @charlietfl not necessarily. It will still work without.

Comment: not with php... will have an empty $_POST because no key/value pairs are sent and the Content-Type is form encoded

Comment: @Shivam , thank you very much. I ended up using your $.ajax() example that you posted and I now have my code working.  I can now save my data out to a file on my WAMP server directory area.

Comment: @J.Laderoute your welcome. Please mark green thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Default `Content-Type` for jQuery ajax data is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is very easy to work with in php using `$_GET` , `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST` and doesn't require stringifying as json

Pass an object directly to `$.post` (or any of the $.ajax methods) and jQuery will encode it internally

```
var data ={foo:'bar'};
$.post('taskmanager.php', data, function(resp){
   console.log(resp);
})
```

php

```
echo $_POST['foo'];
```

---

If you want to work with json only you need to set appropriate Content-Type

```
$.ajax({
   url:'...',
   method:'post',
   contentType:'application/json',
   dataType:'json',
   data: JSON.stringify(data)
}).done(function(resp){
   console.log(resp);
});
```

Then in php use:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$data['foo'] ='Some new value';
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't end up using your ajax example but I did end up using your php example code.  I can't tell you if your ajax() js example works or not as I've not tested it. I ended up using what @Shivam posted for the .ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following to POST JSON to php...

```
$.post("publishdata.php", {
    dataArray: arrayOfStuff,
    meetingTitle: meetingTitle,
    meetingDate: meetingDate
},
function(data, status, response) {

     console.log(response);


});
```

Comment: is easy but this is not json, important distinction

Comment: @tamak : What you posted looks interesting. What would the php script look like to handle that $.post call?