# How can i change SQL query of a fetching page that was included in index page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

In order to fetch Posts whenever the user scrolls, i created an Ajax script that does the trick.
The Ajax script includes a page called fetch_posts.php in index.php that contains the HTML code of the generated posts.


[image]

I wanted to make the search bar, category menu and location menu filter the posts after the user hits the search button, i tried to send the $sql variable **from** index.php **to** fetch_posts.php but it didn't work.


How can i send **$sql(generated depends on the search/category/location)** from index.php to fetch_posts.php?


Ajax script in `index.php`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var limit = 10;
  var start = 0;
  var action = 'inactive';

  function load_data(limit, start){
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch_posts.php",
      method:"POST",
      data:{limit:limit, start:start},
      cache:false,
      success:function(data){
        $('#posts_container').append(data);
        if (data == ''){
          $('#load_data_message').html('<p style="font-family:Helvetica;">No More Posts Available.</p>');
          action = 'active';
        } else {
          $('#load_data_message').html('<img src="res/gif/loading.gif" class="loading-index" height="30px" width="30px"/><p class="load_message" style="font-family:Helvetica;">&nbsp;Loading...</p>');
          action = 'inactive';
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (action == 'inactive'){
    action = 'active';
    load_data(limit, start);
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#posts_container").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_data(limit, start);
   }, 1000);
  }
 });


});
</script>
```

`fetch_posts.php` code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["limit"], $_POST["start"])){
  include 'includes/config.php';

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$_POST["start"].", ".$_POST["limit"];

  $check = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $check->fetch()) {
    $first_id = $row['id'];
    $item_mine = $row['item_mine'];
    $item_wanted = $row['item_wanted'];
    $item_desc = $row['item_description'];
    $item_category = $row['item_category'];
    $item_location = $row['item_location'];
    $item_pub = $row['publishing_date'];
    $item_exp = $row['expiring_date'];

    $image_1 = $row['image_1'];
    $image_2 = $row['image_2'];
    $image_3 = $row['image_3'];
    $image_4 = $row['image_4'];

    $first_image = "";

    $link = "post-".$first_id;

    if ($image_1 === ""){
      $first_image = "res/img/img_select.png";
    } else {
      $first_image = $image_1;
    }

    echo 'Html Content';

    }
  }


 ?>
```

Comment: Can you plz provide the code the you have written.

Comment: Done! i've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    
    include 'includes/config.php';
    $start = $_POST["start"];
    $limit = $_POST["limit"];
    $category = $_POST["category"];
    $location = $_POST["location"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$start.", ".$limit;
    
    // etc..

}
```

Well other things are ok but use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` instead of directly using `isset($_POST["limit"], $_POST["start"])` in the condition. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'` will give you much more freedom. You can use your method by adding additional information `{limit:limit, start:start, catg:catg, etc..}` in the `data` in your ajax method.

**Additional Note**: You try using json data format for sending data. I have added a question link for reference.(It's up to you. I personally use json data formmat for sending and receiving data form the server[file.php])

Link: [How do I use jQuery.post to send JSON data to a php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991889/14235823)